# Detecting position of mouse click within an image on varied screen sizes - Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pixel, jquery-events, mouse-position

I've got an initial div called "container" which is a `height:100% width:100%` image of an Oklahoma map. The idea is that when the user clicks a certain section of the map (for this example, the panhandle), the div is toggled to a div which is the panhandle image. I determine where the user clicks by knowing the pixel location of the mouse when it clicks.

The problem is, pixel values are different for different size screens. Below is the code which works for my own sized window, but when I run the code for the actual program, the window is smaller and thus the area described within the `if` statement is not around the panhandle.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#container").click(function(e)
    {
        var x = event.pageX;
        var y = event.pageY;

        if(x >= 45 && x <= 550 && y >= 245 && y <= 330) 
        {
            //alert('You clicked the panhandle!');
            $("#region1").toggle();
            $("#container").toggle();
        }
}); 
});
```

I'm thinking I need to change how I handle the situation within the `if` statement. How would you approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scale every value before you compare it. Multiply every x by your canonical width and divide by the actual width and do the same with y and height.

Comment: Again, thank you for posting how to scale the values. It's a lot more helpful than simply telling me that I need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not assume definite pixel values and expect your site to work on a variety of devices and browsers -- especially on things like iPads or Android tablets where you have the complication of zooming and dpi settings etc.

My recommendation is to always use % of width and height for your position/size specifications.  For example, your pan handle may be located at (0.23,0.76) and with size (0.12,0.08) etc.

In any browser, get the box dimensions and multiply these % values to get the actual pixel values.

Comment: Thank you for explaining -how- to get the % dimensions. I knew this was the direction to go towards but was unsure of how to do it.